# Access Database Design(multilevel) with Exporting Issue for Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, database-design

Hi I am currently working on a project that contains individual information for each month and I want to build a table or two to contain the information(I don't want to create a table for each month). a simple illustration will be :

Jan

```
        weight      height
```

student a

student b

Feb

```
        weight      height
```

student a
student b
student c

what I what is just to export data to excel in the form of the above, weight, height column are fixed but I want to have data clustered by month so that the data organization is clearer.

May I ask how to design the database so that the abovementioned requirement could be met? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the tables you'll need to store the information:

```
students
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(50)

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Tina |
| .. | .... |
+----+------+
```

In the `measurements` table the Primary Key is formed by the `student_id`, `year` and `month`. The `student_id` is also a foreign key to the `students` table.

```
measurements
    student_id      unsigned int(F students.id)-\
    year            unsigned int ----------------(P)
    month           unsigned int ---------------/
    height          unsigned int
    weight          unsigned int

+------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
| student_id | year | month | height | weight |
+------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
|          1 | 2013 |    11 |     70 |    200 |
|          2 | 2013 |    11 |     65 |    130 |
|          1 | 2013 |    12 |     70 |    192 |
|          2 | 2013 |    12 |     65 |    126 |
|          3 | 2013 |    12 |     68 |    140 |
| .......... | .... | ..... | ...... | ...... |
+------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

And then a query to extract the information:

```
SELECT name, height, weight, year, month
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN measurements m ON s.id = m.student_id
ORDER BY year, month, name
```

Which will give you:

```
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+
| name | height | weight | year | month |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+
| John |     70 |    200 | 2013 |    11 |
| Mary |     65 |    130 | 2013 |    11 |
| John |     70 |    192 | 2013 |    12 |
| Mary |     65 |    126 | 2013 |    12 |
| Tina |     68 |    140 | 2013 |    12 |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+
```

Which is the data you want, sorted in the way you want. Any further formatting of the data is up to your application.